# When the wordpress plugin is activated, the local version of jquery does not work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

WordPress 4.9.4.
The default jquery 1.12.4 was replaced by 3.3.1

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/libs/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), '3.3.1', false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Everything worked fine, but after the activation of the plugin "NextGEN Gallery". I see that, in the head of the site, instead of 3.3.1, again 1.12.4:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.loc/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.loc/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1"></script>
```

I think that the plugin remapped my version of jquery to its version.
and in the console writes that:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
javascript.js?ver=4.9.4:18 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at setVideoHeightHome (javascript.js?ver=4.9.4:18)
at initCustomJs (javascript.js?ver=4.9.4:89)
at javascript.js?ver=4.9.4:96
```

I also see in my custom js of the footer, forgot what is - "$".

The most interesting is that if you add a version from the CDN of Google, that is:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js", false, '3.3.1');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Everything is working fine as before! But the local version does not work.
Actually the question.
Why is that? why CDN works, and local - no, and how to make the local copy work again? Thanks!

**the code in the theme / child theme in the functions.php file**

```
function javascripts_init() {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . 
  '/libs/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), '3.3.1', false);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 
  '/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascript.js', 
  array(), false, true);

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'javascripts_init' );
```

Comment: your code is from your theme/child theme, right? can you provide the full function of registering newest version of jquery( with action )?

Comment: yes, the code in the theme / child theme in the functions.php file
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'javascripts_init' );

Comment: have you got a `$.noConflict` anywhere? this is probably first thing to try :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue related to the plugin *NextGEN Gallery*( as you mentioned ). It's adding `jquery` using both with `global object scripts` and 2 actions: `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `wp_print_scripts`.

You're trying to replace `jquery` with action `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which fires before the second hook. So, after changing your `jquery` version with `wp_enqueue_scripts`, that plugin fires their function with `wp_print_scripts` hook and rolled back the version of script.

So, instead of using

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'javascripts_init' );
```

use:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'javascripts_init');
//or with higher priority, if this will not help. Like
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'javascripts_init', 20);
```

Note: Replacing the default version of `jquery` with newest one may raise a lot of issues with plugins, themes. Just because they all were developed under default WordPress scripts.